# Why does Eclipse think this project is broken?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

Not the red 'X' decorating the Project Name in the Project Explorer window, at the top left of the screen snippet. I expanded all the folders and there are no other error indicators. The code has no red squiggles.

When I execute the project I do get the dialog "Errors exist in required project(s)" but the code does execute and generate the desired results.

[image: Why is the red X appearing?]

Comment: Open the Problems view and see what it says there.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that existed.